# node.jsのmoduleをmockする方法

Tags: javascript, node.js

下記のコードのsomeUtilをテスト時にスタブにできないか試行錯誤しています。

```
var someUtil = require('great-util');

module.export = {
    "action": function() { someUtil.method(); }
}
```

苦肉の策で現状はmoduleの実装とinterfaceを分割して行っています。

```
module.export = {
     "action": function() { Module.actiomImpl(someUtil) },
     "actionImpl": function(someUtil){ someUtil.method() }
}
```

moduleのsomeUtilをスタブにしたいと考えているのですが、上記のような実装のnode_moduleの依存性を解決する方法を教えていただけますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire)というモジュールを利用すると、便利です。

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

proxyquire("./path/to/use/site", {"great-util": {
    method: function() { /* this is mock */ }
}});
```

第1引数に渡した文字列のモジュールから読み込む依存モジュールの実装が、第2引数に渡したオブジェクトになります。
第2引数は、キーがモジュール名、値が`module.exports`に与える実装オブジェクトです。

[私の利用例](https://github.com/mysticatea/uptodate/blob/master/test/lib/override-opener.js)では、ブラウザを開くモジュールをSpyに置き換えています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。これで問題が解決できました！

Answer (score 1):

スタブをローカルモジュールとして用意する方法は使えませんか？

`../stab_modules/great-util` など適当なディレクトリで、`npm init` して、package.json は `"private" : true` に、great-util のスタブモジュールを作成。

使う側で、

```
npm install ../stab_modules/great-util
```

切り替えるには、`npm install great-util` が必要ですが
great-util を使用する側は、スタブが作成できてれば、いつも通り使えるはず。